# How to get IIS web working with server FQDN name

Tags: iis, web-hosting, iis-6

Hope you are all well. I a new to IIS and was wondering if you could help me with an issue I am stuck with
the site is accessible using IP address, and via the shortname http://sitename However, when I try to access the site with an FQDN its complaining a 403 permission denied error. I checked and the permissions are all in place as needed. I did read online that it could be to do with DNS so upon checking I can confirm DNS also resolves fine. it is set up as a server farm with 2 other servers and I have checked the IIS log and I noticed that the request is routed to other servers in the farm and I see that the user account used is as below
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko  - 403 0 0 3
I dont have Firefox installed on the machine. I'm  a bit lost here if anyone could help me please.
Thank you in advance

re-created the site with no luck
re-added the permissions of IIS user with no luck
checked dns
checked folder permissions

Comment: You need to enable FRT and see from where such 403.0 comes. I don't think you are running a normal web app but something huge with its logic on how to respond to certain requests. Thus, any attempt to resolve it based on IIS knowledge (changing permissions) can be on the wrong path.

Comment: Thank you Lex. I should have added this part the version of IIS being used is version 6 and for FRT the version required shows as IIS7

Comment: Then I doubt how much help you might get from here. Most people are on IIS 10 (as older releases are either end of life or almost there), so some knowledge is lost for ever.

Comment: Thank you so much Lex. Appreciate you trying to help me. If I am able to find anything I will post it here.